# How to handle the guest room popup in Redbus in Selenium

Tags: select, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am automating the **RedBus application**. Here, I have to select the Hotel name, check in date , check out date, guest room and Search button. I am selecting the  Hotel name, check in date , check out date.
But when I select the Guest room, the **guest room popup** opens,I am able to select the 3 rooms but after that the popup does not get closed. So it does not click on Search button.
Anyone help me to handle this popup?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("guest_count")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ilbl selectbox a 
    control']//select")).click();


Select selectRoom=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ilbl selectbox a control']//select")));

selectRoom.selectByVisibleText("3");
Thread.sleep(500);
driver.findElement(By.id("search_hotel")).click();
```

Screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t2rLYD36g4w7eiAn9lhhimipdDhmWoQ2

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB Are you serious?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sir it's all your creation :)

Comment: @DebanjanB Ha ha. I didn't understand that, but just asking you, if you have read the question. Looks fine to me. That's why the question. Sorry if I offended you...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sir we are lead by the example you have set, no offence taken :)

Answer (score 1):

Your script **clicks** on the **Search** button. Since your script **hasn't selected any city**, a pop-up comes out to select a city. If you select a city using the snippet below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_key\"]")).sendKeys("bangalore");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_wrapper\"]/div[2]/div/div[1]")).click();
```

then click **Search**, it would give you the expected results.

I used the following code snippet and it did **click** on the **Search** button and yielded the expected result.

```
driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/hotels/");
String windowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_key\"]")).sendKeys("Radisson Blu Resort Goa");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"search_wrapper\"]/div[2]/div/div[1]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("guest_count")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ilbl selectbox a control']//select")).click();

Select selectRoom = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ilbl selectbox a control']//select")));

selectRoom.selectByVisibleText("3");
Thread.sleep(500);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id=\"search_hotel\"]")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I am booking the hotel here. So I am selecting the hotel name, check in date, check out date. But while selecting room it is not responding.

Comment: Added the code snippet to my answer. Hope this helps.